# Fixed point of transition kernel generates martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $P^{h}, h \geqslant 0$ be a transition kernel for some homogenous Markov process $X_t$, $\mathbb{E}|X_t|<\infty$:
$$
   P_{X_{t+h},X_t}(A,B) = \int\limits_{A}P^h(x,B)P_{X_t}(dx)
$$
where $P_{X_{t+h},X_{t}}(A,B) = \mathbb{P}(X_{t+h}\in A, X_{t} \in B)$ and $P_{X_t}(C) = \mathbb{P}(X_t \in C)$. Then $P^h$ can be considered as a linear operator acting on continuous bounded functions:
$$
   P^h f(x) = \int f(y)P^h(x,dy)
$$ 
Let $f(x)$ be a fixed point of $P^h$ for any $h \geqslant 0$: $P^h f = f$. Now let $\mathcal{F}_{t} = \sigma(X_{s} \mid s \leqslant t)$ be a sigma-algebra generated by $\{X_s \mid s \leqslant t\}$. I want to show that
$$
   \mathbb{E}( f(X_{t+s}) \mid \mathcal{F}_t) = f(X_t)
$$
for any $s \geqslant 0$. I can do it informally:
$$
   \mathbb{E}( f(X_{t+s}) \mid X_{t}=x ) = \int f(y) P^{s}(x,dy) = P^s f(x) = f(x).
$$
Please help me to do it strictly.

Comment: Which book are you using to study Markov processes?

Comment: @Ilya I don't use some particular book, I try to obtain given theorems myself, but when I have no ideas I look Shiryaev's "Probability".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using some non-usual formulas for the kernels of the Markov process. I think, it better to start with the following:
$$
  \mathsf P_x(X_{t+h}\in B|\mathscr F_t) = \mathsf P_{X_t}(X_h\in B)=P^h(X_t,B)
$$
where the first identity is the definition of the Markov property, and the second one is the definition of the kernel. Clearly, just by writing integrals you have the very same expression for the expectations (at least for bounded measurable functions):
$$
  \mathsf E_x\left[f(X_{t+h})|\mathscr F_t\right] = \mathsf E_{X_t}[f(X_h)]=(P^hf)(X_t) \stackrel{harm}{=}f(X_t),
$$
where $\stackrel{harm}{=}$ holds under the assumption $f$ is harmonic: $P^sf =f$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have a question: why $\mathscr{F}_{t} = \sigma(X_{s} \mid s\leqslant t)$ is equal to $\sigma(X_t)$? I think that's because $X_t$ is a Markov process, but how to show this?

Comment: My second question: why $\mathsf E_{X_t} f(X_{t+h}) = (\mathsf P^h f)(X_t)$? LHS is $\mathscr F_{X_t}$-measurable, then there exists Borel function $\varphi(x)$ such that $\mathsf E_{X_t} f(X_{t+h}) = \varphi(X_t)$. By definition $\mathsf E(f(X_{t+h}) \mid X_t=x) := \varphi(x)$. But why $\varphi(x) = P^h f (x)$?

Comment: I've asked the latter question in a separate post: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/281431/16273.

Comment: @Nimza: the answer to the first question is no. But conditioning on these $\sigma$-algebras for $X_u$ with $u\geq t$ is equivalent. When $u<t$ the conditioning is not equivalent.

Comment: @Nimza: for the second question, this follows from the fact that $\mathsf P_{X_t}(X_h\in B) = P^h(X_t,B)$ *by the definition* of the transition kernel $P^h$ as I as said above. Would you agree on this? Then be integrating $f$ w.r.t. this measure you get the formula for the expectation.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But how to show that $\mathsf E(X_{t+h}|\mathscr F_{t}) = \mathsf E(X_{t+h} \mid X_t)$ for $h > 0$?

Comment: @Nimza Well, the quantities you are talking are undefined since $\mathsf E$ acts only on linear spaces and $X_t$ does not have to belong to a linear space. The true formula is 
$$
  \mathsf E_x[f(X_{t+h})|\mathscr F_t] = \mathsf E_x[f(X_{t+h})|X_t]
$$
for any bounded measurable $f$. This is exactly the (non-strong) Markov property. If you have doubts about that, please tell me which form of the Markov property are you aware of.